# Accessing Objects in other Layers (cocos2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I was playing around with a Joystick moving a Sprite around in one layer. Now, according to best practice, the Joystick and the Sprite have to be in different Layers of the same scene. I have managed to separate these, yet I am now completely stuck having absolutely no clue whatsoever how to pass joystick commands from one layer to another? What is the recommended way to do this?

Scene

- Game Play Layer

  - Sprite
- Game Control Layer

  - Joystick

When the joystick is manipulated I need to pass this info to the GamePlayLayer to control the sprite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I got a great Cocos2d book, written by Rod Strougo and Ray Wenderlich, by the name "Learning Cocos2d". In their book, they implement a game, which has a joystick implemented and all, using your initial setup. The GamePlayLayer contains both the joyStick and the hero sprite. (See book page 40).

I don't believe they would use bad practices in their book, given they are very talented!

...

With that being said, I have possible solutions, if you wish to implement them on separate layers:

```
GameScene
|
|__>GameLayer
|
|__>ControlLayer
```

That's your basic setup. But, intuitively, what is the purpose of the control layer? Control the game layer's content! So, I would suggest you hold a (weak) reference to the GameLayer within the ControlLayer. That way, using a simple:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CCSprite* hero;
```

you now have access to the hero from the ControlLayer!

Extra (if needed):

```
//GameScene init:
- (id)init {
    ....
    gameLayer = [GameLayer node];
    controlLayer = [ControlLayer node];
    [controlLayer setGameLayerRef:gameLayer];
    ...
}

// Control layer:
@property (nonatomic, assign) GameLayer* gameLayerRef;
```

Even though I just suggested that way, I don't use it in my games :)

What I normally do is:

Make the GameScene class a "Semi-Singleton". (I learned this method from "Learn iPhone and iPad Game Dev" By Itterheim (aka gaming horror, Kobold2d publisher ... etc).

Then, inside the control layer, I would call the GameScene object:

```
[[GameScene sharedScene] doSomethingToTheGameLayer];
```

Yeah, the gameScene has simplistic methods that just relies what the control need to update in the game layer.

---

#### Edit:

Implementing the Semi-singleton pattern, as described by Itterheim in his book.

**But, what is semi-singleton?**

It has the singleton pattern's property: you can access the object instance from anywhere using a static call.

```
[GameScene sharedScene];
```

However, singleton objects are usually retained, after being created for the first time, till the end of the application's life. In the Semi-singleton pattern, this is not the case.

Once you create the instance, you cannot create another instance before destroying the old one, BUT once you are done with the instance, *you destroy it (dealloc)*. Creating another one when necessary.

Recap:
Semi-Singleton: Create many object from it, but only one at any given time. Only recreate after destroying the old.

**Implementation:**

Of course, as you do with any singleton class, you first declare a static variable of the same type of the class:

```
//In GameScene.m
static GameScene* instance = nil;

@implementation

//Here we have the static method to access the instance:
+(GameScene*)sharedScene {
    //you must have created one before trying to access it "Globally".
    ///Typically, created where you transition the GameScene using CCDirector's replaceScene.
    NSAssert(instance != nil, @"GameScene not instantiated!!");
    return instance;
}

-(id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        //Make sure you don't have another instance of the class created
        //NOTE: Possible race condition that I wouldn't worry about, since it should never happen.
        NSAssert(instance == nil, @"Another instance is already created!!");
        instance = self;

        ...
    }
    return self;
}

//Don't forget!! Dealloc!!
- (void)dealloc {
    //the only instance we had is dealloc'd! We are back to zero. Can create a new one later! :D
    instance = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

#### Edit2:

So, the timeline:

```
CCScene* scene = [GameScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
...
[[GameScene sharedScene] doSomething];
...
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:otherScene];
//After the new scene replaces GameScene, dealloc will be called, implicitly. Making instance = nil;
instance = nil;
[super dealloc];
...
//Loop again
CCScene* scene = [GameScene node];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:scene];
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply! I have followed the book by "Rod Strougo" and got quite far. However, other authors for eg. "Steffen Itterheim" (whom you have also mentioned) have other ideologies. And as I am still learning Cocos2d and Objective-C I just wanted to explore both approaches. Could you please give me a bit more insight into the Semi-Singleton pattern, as it sounds much more reasonable to me than keeping a weak-reference, as I am an advocate of total encapsulation ;-)